# Modify lambda expression in extension method

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, linq-to-objects, func

I'm trying to create an extension method with Generics in which you receive a List of
whatever class, for example:

```
 class User
 {
  public string name {get;set;}
  public int age {get;set;}
  public string lastLogon {get;set;}
 }
```

I am trying to build an expresion in which you pass to the extension method the IEnumerable and you specify which is the string date property. (In this case `lastLogon`)

Without extension method It should be something like:

```
userList.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.lastLogon));
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
 public static IEnumerable<TSource> OrderEnumerablebyDatetimeString<TSource,TKey>(
            this IEnumerable<TSource> input, Func<TSource, TKey> funcexpr)
        {
            //modify expression to get the date field and modify the lambda expr
            Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> expr = ???

            return input.OrderBy(funcexpr);

        }
```

My final extension call should look like:

```
userList.OrderEnumerablebyDatetimeString(x => x.lastLogon);
```

Comment: use `Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> funcexpr` instead of `Func<TSource, TKey> funcexpr`

Comment: Grundy is right, if this is Linq-to-SQL.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen i mean that after modify call `Compile` and use with `IEnumerable`

Comment: This is linq to objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I've got for you:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> OrderEnumerablebyDatetimeString<TSource>(
this IEnumerable<TSource> input, Func<TSource, string> funcexpr)
{
    Func<TSource, DateTime> expr = (x=>Convert.ToDateTime(funcexpr(x)));

    return input.OrderBy(expr);

}
```

Note that I removed and changed some of the generic parameters to more accurate reflect what you have. You've said you're always passing in a string so the fun you pass in should always return a string. Likewise the Expression you are creating for your orderby will always be returning a DateTime so I have hardcoded that.

The key bit of course is calling the passed `Func` to get the date string from the object.

To explain that in more detail (as requested in comments) `funcexpr(x)` is calling the func that you passed in with x as its parameter. Its much like calling any other method except your method is in a variable. Specifically func has been declared to be a method that accepts an object and returns a `string`. In this case the string is the date string from the object which in our example is a user. So `funcexpr(x)` will return the date string that is then converted to a DateTime by convert as you would expect.

I should also note for completeness that this was done and tested in a Linq to Objects context. Which I assume since you are talking about working with `List<User>` is the case.

Also here is a link to a working sample, including a string sort as well to prove its working properly: http://dotnetfiddle.net/r3Lq0P

Comment: `IEnumerable` extensions need `Func` not an `Expression`

Comment: @Grundy: Need might be too strong a work given the code above was tested and works in linqpad. You are right that it doesn't need it though so it will be cleaner to remove it.

Comment: Just noticed my testing was shocking though given I didn't use expr. ;-)

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it is not ordering the List. Here you have an example: http://pastebin.com/05eHKr51

Comment: In your example they are already in date order so there shouldn't be any change. http://pastebin.com/7m97Qk5C is the code that I used in LinqPad to test and this does change the order to test3,test1,test2 when run. In this test note that the date format I used in the string is designed to ensure that string and date comparisons will result in different results.

Comment: Thank you very much. Accept and +1 for great help

Comment: I've added a note to my answer giving more detail on that key line. padding shouldn't make a difference to how it works because the conversion shouldn't care about whitespace. Sounds like you have got over whatever problem it was though. :)

Comment: you are a machine Chris ;)

Comment: I just like linq and funcs and all that kind of stuff. :) Once you are experienced with this sort of things its the writing it up that takes more time than working out the answer. ;)